# how to show all features visible on map?

Tags: qgis

i have restored on mssql a backup file and added it on qgis but it shows only some features NOT all features. i want all features to be shown on map.

Comment: Are you sure that they were present in the backup? How did you backup/restore your database?

Comment: yes they are and they are on qgis on all features tab but in visible on map are only 130. i want to show all in map